# SSRS - Combining 2 datasets from 2 different data sources

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to set up a SSRS report where I combine 2 datasets connected to 2 different data sources. The parameter @ParentProductID is used in both dataset queries.

---

**DataSet01**

- ParentProductID
- ChildProductID
- Quantity

Example output

```
+-----------------+----------------+----------+
| ParentProductID | ChildProductID | Quantity |
+-----------------+----------------+----------+
|               1 |             20 |       50 |
|               1 |             30 |       10 |
|               1 |             40 |       10 |
|               1 |             50 |       10 |
+-----------------+----------------+----------+
```

---

**DataSet02**

- ParentProductID
- CompanyID

Example output

```
+-----------------+-----------+
| ParentProductID | CompanyID |
+-----------------+-----------+
|               1 |       100 |
|               1 |       200 |
+-----------------+-----------+
```

---

As the data is from 2 different data sources, I have had no luck joining the data in a single dataset query.

What I want is to display a matrix with the following data:

```
+-----------------+-----------+
| ParentProductID | CompanyID |
+-----------------+-----------+
| ChildProductID  | Quantity  |
+-----------------+-----------+
```

So far I’ve managed to combine the table using lookup function. (placeholder expression in "CompanyID" column)

=Lookup(Fields!ParentProductID.Value.tostring(), Fields!ParentProductID.Value.tostring(), Fields!CompanyID.Value, "DataSet02a_uCommerceOrder")

However, this only combines the first company where the parent ID matches.

```
+----+-----+
| 1  | 100 |
+----+-----+
| 20 |  50 |
| 30 |  10 |
| 40 |  10 |
| 50 |  10 |
+----+-----+
```

I wish to combine the datasets, so I get a column for each CompanyID, and not just the first occurrence.

```
+----+-----+-----+
| 1  | 100 | 200 |
+----+-----+-----+
| 20 |  50 |  50 |
| 30 |  10 |  10 |
| 40 |  10 |  10 |
| 50 |  10 |  10 |
+----+-----+-----+
```

How can this be done in SSRS?
Can I merge the CompanyID from DataSet02 to DataSet01?

Comment: You need to look at LOOKUPSET rather than LOOKUP.  Is setting up a linked server between the two servers and writing a query over both not an option?

Comment: Hi Harry. No, setting up a linked server is not an option in our scenario.

When using LOOKUPSET, instead of LOOKUP, I am shown the text #Error instead of the CompanyID

=LookupSet(Fields!ParentProductID.Value.tostring(), Fields!ParentProductID.Value.tostring(), Fields!CompanyID.Value.tostring(), "DataSet02a_uCommerceOrder")